# How to update colors of charts created with jquery visualize?

Tags: jquery, colors, charts, visualize

Is there a way to update the colors of a jquery visualize chart when it already has been created?

Thanks

Comment: No, I use slate admin (http://themeforest.net/item/slate-admin/133854) and the charts initialization is done in the template and the code is compressed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You create your chart as usual:

```
var $table = $("table");
var chart = $table.visualize();
```

then you call visualize again, this time passing the existing chart container which you want to update as an argument:

```
$table.visualize({colors:['black','red','green','gray']}, chart);
```

Answer (score 0):

Sure.  Take a look at this page. Try Changing some values and the chart changes.  A View source should all your questions!

http://www.filamentgroup.com/examples/charting_v2/index_2.php